# TeXLive light version installed from a deb file

Tags: deb, latex

In this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262706/99876), it is explained how a light version of TeXLive can be installed with the `--no-install-recommends` option, like this:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends texlive-latex-extra
```

In the case of using a deb file to install TeXLive, how can you mimic the `--no-install-recommends` option to prevent extra documentation from being downloaded? What to add to the `texlive-fonts-recommended (>= 2015.20160320-1ub)` dependence?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is globally block recommended packages for a while by creating an apt rule: https://superuser.com/a/615583

Then do the usual `aptitude update` before installing your .deb file.

After that, just delete the rule and do `aptitude update` again.